# Change constraint of my custom UIView with its parent VC bottom layout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

I have a custom UIView which I want to reuse over and over on more than a half of the VCs of my project. Moreover, on all these VCs it should be located at the bottom.

For some reason I want to change its bottom constraint with bottomLayoutGuide on action. It's easy to do if I do not care about reusing this construction. Then I can change this constraint using outlet for my view. However it would mean that I have to duplicate code in other VCs.

How can I avoid such kind of repetition and reuse my custom view which constraint to current VC bottomLayoutGuide can be change on action?

Comment: add that code so i can help you for optimise that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a class which is the subclass of nsobject and write function just like this.
import  framework before that in that subclass.

```
+ (UIView*)makeCustomViewWithBottomConstraint:(NSInteger)bottomConstant andHeight:(NSInteger)viewHeight inViewController:(UIViewController*)vc{

    UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    [vc.view addSubview:customView];
    customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"viewHeight":@(viewHeight),
                              @"bottomConstant":@(bottomConstant)};
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(customView);

    NSArray *hConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|"
                                                                              options:0
                                                                              metrics:metrics
                                                                                views:views];
    NSArray *vConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[view(viewHeight)]-bottomConstant-|"
                                                                              options:0
                                                                              metrics:metrics
                                                                                views:views];



    [vc.view addConstraints:hConstraint];
    [vc.view addConstraints:vConstraint];

    return customView;

}
```

and access this class method in your desired view controller like this

```
[CustomViewClass makeCustomViewWithBottomConstraint:0 andHeight:40 inViewController:self];
```

I have added the sample project in GitHub. Sorry for objective C. I still love this language.
[github link](https://github.com/junaid4058/stackAnswer1)